# Deference index in a numpy submatrix in the large matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix `a` and a submatrix `b` of `a`. Is there a possibility to get the index of `a` that corresponds to the `i,j`-th element in the indexing by `b`?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = a[3:]
b[2] == a[5]
        ^^^^
```

How would I get this 5 systematically? Does `b` expose some method to 'dereference' indices?

Edit: I find using `np.where(a==b[2])` dissatisfactory: it involves traversing all of `a`. I would have thought that `b` has some information where to find its`i`-th element in `a`. Is this the case?

Comment: Do you mean `np.where(a==b[2])`?

Comment: @anky this involves traversing the array `a`, but I'd have assumed that `b` stores the information how it relates to `a`.

Comment: `b` is a numpy array, just like `a`.  It does not store extra information, except indirectly in how it references the shared data buffer.  You have to use your own knowledge based on how you created `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [58]: a = np.arange(10)
In [59]: b = a[3:]
```

The basic information of an array can be seen with:

```
In [60]: a.__array_interface__
Out[60]: 
{'data': (46666800, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (10,),
 'version': 3}
```

`b` is similar, except shape is different, and 'data'` number if 24 larger, 3*8 bytes.

```
In [61]: b.__array_interface__
Out[61]: 
{'data': (46666824, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (7,),
 'version': 3}
```

`b` also has a `base` attribute:

```
In [62]: b.base
Out[62]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [63]: b
Out[63]: array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

In theory you could deduce the offset between `b` and `a` by comparing the `__array_interface__['data'][0]` values, but there isn't a publicly available function or method that does it, and I'm not sure about the general utility of it.

An example of a more general view:

```
In [64]: a[9:2:-2]
Out[64]: array([9, 7, 5, 3])
In [65]: a[9:2:-2].__array_interface__
Out[65]: 
{'data': (46666872, False),    # different
 'strides': (-16,),            # different
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (4,),                # different
 'version': 3}
```

The whole point to this `view` mechanism is that it allows `numpy` to make new arrays with a minimum of extra baggage.  `data` is copied when the new array can't reference the original `data` with a simple change in `shape`, `strides`, pointer and `dtype`.